# G.drawimage draws with incorrect size

Tags: c#, bitmap, drawimage

Im creating a big bitmap which contains some smaller images from files. The images have both a size of 250px, but one of them gets smaller and the other bigger than 250px. I'm just using the basic g.drawimage method, so I don't get what I do wrong.

```
string[] imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images");
ArrayList images = new ArrayList();

foreach (var item in imagePaths)
    images.Add(new Bitmap(item, true));

Bitmap list = new Bitmap(840, 1188);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(list);

int size = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
{
    g.DrawImage((Bitmap)images[i], new Point(10, (i + 1) * 10 + size));
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)images[i];
    Console.WriteLine(bmp.Height);
    Font drawFont = new Font("Arial", 16);
    size += bmp.Height;
    g.DrawString(imagePaths[i].Substring(imagePaths[i].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, imagePaths[i].Length - imagePaths[i].LastIndexOf("\\") - 4), drawFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(bmp.Width + 30, (i + 1) * 10 + size / 4));
}    

list.Save(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\list.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Are you certain about their original size? Try opening them with Paint and see the exact size through the x,y in bottom left corner

Comment: Yeah sure, they are both at 250px. One of them is 40 kb bigger tho

Comment: I need more info to see what the problem is. All the code you feel relevant shall suffice.

Comment: did you resolve your problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't set the dpi values. These are honored in `DrawImage`, so you need to set them with `bitmap.SetResolution(dpix, dpiy)`. When they are different in the images the results will be too. You can get the 'correct' one from the `Graphics` object `g` or decide what you want.

Quick fix:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            ((Bitmap)images[i]).SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY);
            g.DrawImage((Bitmap)images[i], new Point(10, (i + 1) * 10 + size));
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)images[i];
            ...
        }
```

Note that the newly created bitmap uses the screen dpi resolution as its default. If you want to control the dpi you need to set them for `list` as well!

Also note the I didn't change your code; to simplify the last line should really move to the top of the loop and then `bmp` be used instead of the array element..

Comment: When painting on a new freshly made image, you can get around the dpi problems simply by using a `Rectangle` instead of a `Point`, and giving it the painted image's dimensions. It'll "resize" the image to the given size instead of applying the dpi.

Comment: True. But calculating the Rectangle is not really easier than setting uniform dpi values, is it?

Comment: There's nothing to calculate; a rectangle isn't initialised from 4 coordinates, it's made from an origin point and dimensions. All you need to do is give the same origin point values you already do, and the image width and height as the two other args.

Comment: That said, your dpi-focused answer has the added value of explaining _why_ it goes wrong. But it has the disadvantage that it changes the painted image object's properties for a processing step that should not affect that object it in any way..

Comment: The source object is not really changed, unless you store it. The Rectangle's size must be determined somehow, depending on the OP's needs. Two valid ways to control the resulting size.

Comment: The actual image _source_ may not be changed, but the image _object_ definitely is. I consider it bad form to change properties on objects on an operation that only uses them as side resources. The operation is not _supposed_ to modify the image objects in that array. They may still be used for other stuff...

Comment: Well, you are right in principle; but I do not see how the principle applies here. We know nothing about the application, do we? And what is done is to __normalize__ a series of resources to have pixels of the same size, ie only those images are changed which have a 'wrong' dpi value.

Comment: Oh, I'm not criticizing. Was indeed just pointing out technicalities.