# Print picture from PictureBox in original picture size

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

In C# how to print an image shown in the picture box with the actual dimensions of the picture not the dimensions of the PictureBox?
Here I have this code that I use to print the image, but it is printed according to the height and width of the PictureBox and not the height and width of the original image:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Pbox.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, Pbox.Width, Pbox.Height));
}
```

Comment: Well, obviously use Pbox.Image.Width and Height?

Comment: Note that DrawImage will honor the dpi settings. So to control the printed size best set the dpi values of the Image/Bitmap..: [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990351/g-drawimage-draws-with-incorrect-size/48991166#48991166) - Now use an overload without a rectangle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the actual dimensions of the image, you can use the `PhysicalDimension` image.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(Pbox.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)Pbox.Image.PhysicalDimension.Width, (int)Pbox.Image.PhysicalDimension.Height));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved the problem